# Git: Shortcut for a merge workflow that includes an interactive rebase

Tags: git

When I want to bring the changes from a feature branch into my master branch, I often do the following:

```
$ git checkout feature-branch
$ git rebase -i master # Clean up the history
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard feature-branch
```

Is there a shortcut for this sequence of commands?

**EDIT:** Tim Biegeleisen points out that instead of running `git reset --hard feature-branch` I might simply `git merge feature-branch`. What I would like to have though is a shortcut like `git rebase-merge feature-branch` that results in the same master branch as my sequence of commands.

Comment: What is happening inside that interactive rebase?  We sort of need to know this to be able to answer your question, I think.

Comment: Often I reorder or squash commits, or edit commit messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write yourself a little script or alias that does the rebase and, if (and only if!) it succeeded, does a fast-forward operation on `master` (given that this is the result you want).

Remember, any rebase can go wrong, either by being aborted by the user or due to a merge failure during one of the cherry-pick steps.  Fortunately `git rebase` itself is a well-behaved Unix / Linux / POSIX tool: it exits zero on success and nonzero on failure, so that you can tell whether it succeeded or failed.  Other Git commands are similar.  Hence this is achievable as small bash / sh shell function:

```
rebase-merge() {
    case $# in
    1) ;; # good
    *) echo "usage: rebase-merge <branch>" 1>&2; exit 1;;
    esac
    git checkout "$1" &&
        git rebase -i master &&
        git checkout master &&
        git merge --ff-only "$1"
}
```

It's possible to smush this into a one-liner expression that goes in your global `.gitconfig` as a Git alias.  I leave doing that as an exercise for the reader.

There are other, fancier ways to do this, but this is literally what you're doing (but simplified to use `git mege --ff-only` to make sure that Git does a fast-forward merge only, or fails if that's not possible), just turned into a command.  I added the check to make sure that "$#" (the number of arguments) is exactly 1, using the construct I prefer since it lets you provide two arguments if you decide you'd like the target branch (currently hardcoded as `master`, twice) to be optional: just change the setup from "case ..." to:

```
case $# in
1) target=master;;
2) target="$2";;
*) echo "usage ..." ...
esac
```

and then use `"$target"` instead of the literal `master`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! :) I'll report back once I've figured out the git alias.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is happening inside the interactive rebase, but I will mention that this is a more typical rebase workflow:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge feature-branch
```

The basic idea being that we rewrite the feature branch by bringing in the latest commits from master, then reapplying the unique commits from the feature branch.  Then, we can just fast forward the master branch with those new commits from the feature branch.

Note that this isn't shorter than what you currently have, but I believe this is the more typical workflow used with rebasing.  Depending on what you do in your interactive rebase, the above workflow I suggested might no longer work.

Comment: I prefer not having merge commits.

Comment: @sjakobi My workflow typically does _not_ result in merge commits.  I suspect that you don't understand rebasing.

Comment: Oh. I just didn't know that fast-forward merges don't result in merge commits. Thanks! Do you know a good way to reduce this series of commands to a single one though?

Comment: @sjakobi Fast forwards _might_ result in a merge commit if someone has configured your repo (e.g. Bitbucket, GitHub) to always make a merge commit.  But, I don't know of a way to make this shorter.